# Return statements in a list

Tags: prolog

If I have the following relation:

```
? friend(tom, X).
X = jim ;
X = tom ;
X = joe ;
X = bob ;
false.
```

How can I turn the output into:

```
X = [jim, tom, joe, bob].
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; I've used `bagof` as part of the solution predicate, as follows:

```
bagof(X, friend(tom, X), Xs).
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to also familiarize yourself with `setof/3` and `findall/3` and how they differ from `bagof/3`.